# msg.value instead of this.balance

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

What the theory behind using msg.value instead of this.balance 
when e.g withdrawing contributed funds from a contract?

E.g

```
wallet.transfer(this.balance);
wallet.transfer(msg.value);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`msg.value` is the amount of ETH sent to a `payable` `public` method in a contract.

`this.balance` is the amount of ETH stored in the contract.